# Website video on blackberry phones

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

I need to create a web page, that shows video on iphone, ipad, blackberry & desktop browsers.
On desktop browsers and ios it works fine. But i have a issue with blackberry.

```
<object data="path_to_3gp_video" type="video/3gpp" title="Some title" width="400"
height="300">
```

After some googling i figured out that this code works fine on blackberry:

```
<a href="rtsp://v3.cache5.c.youtube.com/0/video.3gp"><img 
src="media/prs_poster_ns.jpg"></a>
```

But I need play it on my server, which doesn't supports `rtsp` protocol.
Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few pointers:**

1. Check if Blackberry Browser version is it `v4.6.0` or above, verify it from [this](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/08/blackberry-browser-embedded-media-content-automatic-playback-how-to/) link
2. Check if Blackberry Browser and your server supports `HTTP Progressive Download` as you said `RTSP` is not supported by server
3. Check if the Blackberry OS support `RTSP / HTTP / HTTP-Progressive` playback, using [this](https://github.com/mjrusso/videostreaming-blackberry) link

Answer (score 0):

Find your device here [supported media types](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18349/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf) and check what video format does it support.